# mpdf division by zero when using images

Tags: php, mpdf

Im attempting to build pdfs using the mpdf library...

```
        include('convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php');


        // build the content for the preview...

        ob_start();

                include (DIR_BOOKS.'/'.$book_path.'/preview-male.php');
                $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); 

        // build the overlay on the child image 

        $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(221,221));


        $stylesheet = file_get_contents(DIR_BOOKS.$book_path.'/stylesheet.css');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);      

        $mpdf->Output(DIR_TEMPORARY_IMAGES.$this->session->data['pdf_id'].'.pdf','F');
```

Then the code in mpdf where Im getting the errors...

```
$this->WriteHTML($html , 4);    // parameter 4 saves output to $this->headerbuffer
$actual_h = $this->y - $y;
$use_w = $w;
$use_h = $h;

//Line 13865 
$ratio = $actual_h / $use_w;

if ($overflow!='hidden' && $overflow!='visible') {
    //Line 13868 
    $target = $h/$w;
    if (($ratio / $target ) > 1) {
        $nl = CEIL($actual_h / $this->lineheight);
        $l = $use_w * $nl;
        $est_w = sqrt(($l * $this->lineheight) / $target) * 0.8;
        $use_w += ($est_w - $use_w) - ($w/100);
    }
    //Line 13875
    $bpcstart = ($ratio / $target);
    $bpcctr = 1;
    while(($ratio / $target ) > 1) {

        if ($this->progressBar) { $this->UpdateProgressBar(4,intval(100/($ratio/$target)),('Auto-sizing fixed-position block: '.$bpcctr++)); }  // *PROGRESS-BAR*

        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;

        if (($ratio / $target) > 1.5 || ($ratio / $target) < 0.6) {
            $use_w += ($w/$this->incrementFPR1);
        }
        else if (($ratio / $target) > 1.2 || ($ratio / $target) < 0.85) {
            $use_w += ($w/$this->incrementFPR2);
        }
        //Line 13890
        else if (($ratio / $target) > 1.1 || ($ratio / $target) < 0.91) {
            $use_w += ($w/$this->incrementFPR3);
        }
        else {
            $use_w += ($w/$this->incrementFPR4);
        }

        $use_h = $use_w * $target ;
        $this->rMargin=$this->w - $use_w - $x;
        $this->pgwidth = $this->w - $this->lMargin - $this->rMargin;
        $this->HTMLheaderPageLinks = array();
        $this->HTMLheaderPageAnnots = array();
        $this->HTMLheaderPageForms = array();
        $this->pageBackgrounds = array();
        $this->WriteHTML($html , 4);    // parameter 4 saves output to $this->headerbuffer
        $actual_h = $this->y - $y;
        $ratio = $actual_h / $use_w;
    }
    if ($this->progressBar) { $this->UpdateProgressBar(4,'100',' '); }  // *PROGRESS-BAR*
}
$shrink_f = $w/$use_w;
```

And my php file that im fetching the html from...

```
<div class="page-1-image-1"><img src="https://www.example.com/working-image.jpg" /> </div>
```

Im getting the following errors when I include images in my mpdf html code....

```
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>13865</b>
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>13868</b>
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>13869</b>
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>13875</b>
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/stuff.php</b> on line <b>13877</b>
<b>Warning</b>: Division by zero in <b>/var/www/html/example/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>13910</b>
<B>mPDF error: </B>Please do not use values equal to zero for scaling
```

I have tried both my own images that are freshly generated, but also tried other perfectly good image urls online, and no joy. I have tried both pngs and jpgs.

Im suspecting those errors are coming from an issue where its simply not loading the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us `stuff.php` line: `13860` - `13915`

Comment: You're probably right but in order for people to help you, you need to show how you got to the error. Show code!

Comment: apologies, i will change stuff.php to mpdf.php to be more clear, and will post some code now

Comment: @Adrian Please also mark the lines: `13865`, `13868`, ... with a comment

Comment: Thank you , Ive made more specific changes and added the lines, however I think it would be a given that mpdf library code shouldnt be changed itself as every change has implications on a a different part of script.

Comment: @Adrian wrote a answer, but if you don't want to make changes there, you just have to check/ make sure you never enter values which then are used to divide another number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what's happening is you are trying to divide a number by 0, which is not going to work! It's not allowed in Math. (e.g. `5 / 0 = ? -> ? * 0 = 5`)

As an example this line:

```
$ratio = $actual_h / $use_w;
```

You get a error because `$use_w` is 0! So how do you prevent those errors?

You can make a check like this:

```
if($use_w != 0) {
    //Here you could end the script OR assign it to 1, just make sure you never use $use_w with the value 0
    $ratio = $actual_h / $use_w;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help here, but the main issue Im having is what is giving rise to the 0 in the first place.It seems to be when an image is included in html code that is used to generate the pdf.

Comment: @Adrian I can't help you any further, I only can say you that you have to make sure no value is 0. If it's a bug/problem with mpdf, i can't help you

Comment: This is technically the correct answer in case anyone else arrives along with that php error, thank you